# How do I use a column from a surrounding query as the value for LIMIT in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLite, it's possible to use any expression that returns or can be converted to an integer as the argument to [`LIMIT`](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset).

> Any scalar expression may be used in the LIMIT clause, so long as it evaluates to an integer or a value that can be losslessly converted to an integer. [...]

That means, the following is possible (I'll show the database used for that further below):

```
SELECT * FROM event_attendees
WHERE dtime IS NULL
ORDER BY rtime ASC
LIMIT (
  SELECT max_participants FROM `events` WHERE id = 1
);
```

This query will run and return a result.

However, I am trying to use this inside of a subquery, but that gives me an error message.

```
SELECT *
  FROM `events` e
       JOIN
       event_attendees ON `events`.id = event_attendees.event_id AND 
            event_attendees.id IN (
                SELECT id
                    FROM event_attendees ea2
                    WHERE ea2.dtime IS NULL AND 
                        ea2.event_id = e.id
                    ORDER BY rtime ASC
                    LIMIT e.max_participants
             );
```

In [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/606ab/3) the error message is as follows.

> could not prepare statement (1 no such column: e.max_participants)

When I run it with SQLiteStudio 3 the error message is this:

> Error while executing SQL query on database 'foo': no such column events.max_participants

The schema I'm running this on looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
    id               INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name             VARCHAR,
    max_participants INT
);

CREATE TABLE event_attendees (
    id          INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    event_id    INTEGER  REFERENCES events (id),
    attendee_id INTEGER, /* we don't need attendees for this example */
    rtime       DATETIME NOT NULL,
    dtime       DATETIME
);
```

I use the following example values.

```
INSERT INTO `events` ( id, name,  max_participants) 
VALUES               ( 1,  'foo', 3 ), 
                     ( 2,  'bar', 4 );

INSERT INTO `event_attendees` 
(id, event_id, attendee_id, rtime,                 dtime) VALUES
(1,  1,        1,           '2017-08-02 08:08:00', NULL                 ),
(2,  1,        2,           '2017-08-02 08:09:00', NULL                 ),
(3,  1,        3,           '2017-08-02 08:10:00', NULL                 ),
(4,  1,        4,           '2017-08-02 08:12:00', NULL                 ),
(5,  2,        1,           '2017-08-03 08:08:00', NULL                 ),
(6,  2,        2,           '2017-08-03 08:09:00', '2017-08-04 10:08:00'),
(7,  2,        3,           '2017-08-03 08:10:00', NULL                 ),
(8,  2,        4,           '2017-08-03 08:11:00', NULL                 ),
(9,  2,        5,           '2017-08-03 08:12:00', NULL                 ),
(10, 2,        6,           '2017-08-03 08:13:00', NULL                 ),
(11, 2,        7,           '2017-08-03 08:14:00', NULL                 ),
(12, 2,        8,           '2017-08-03 08:15:00', NULL                 );
```

I've also prepared [an SQLFiddle with this exact data and both these queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/606ab/3).

The tables describe a list of events with people attending them. The table with the users that relates to the `attendee_id` is not relevant to the problem, so I left it out.

I am trying to select the people that signed up for the event first (`rtime`), did not cancel (`dtime`), limited by the `max_participants` attendee cap of the event. The result we should see are the rows with these `event_attendees.id`s.

```
id event_id attendee_id
1  1        1
2  1        2
3  1        3
5  2        1
7  2        3
8  2        4
9  2        5
```

It seems like SQLite is not able to see the `e.max_participants` column from the outside query in the subquery.

Am I missing something, or is this not possible because of some restriction that I am not aware of? Is there another way to to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does indeed [describe](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset) the rules for the expression for a limit:

> Any scalar expression may be used in the LIMIT clause

However, `scalar expression` is not defined in the documentation. I think a better description of it would be "scalar constant".

If you changed the first query to:

```
SELECT ea.*
FROM event_attendees ea
WHERE dtime IS NULL
ORDER BY rtime ASC
LIMIT (SELECT e.max_participants FROM `events` e WHERE e.id = ea.event_id);
```

Then you would understand the problem that the SQLite parser has. The `LIMIT` needs to be a constant, but it changes from one row to the next.

It would seem that SQLite extends this to disallowing correlated subqueries. I don't fully understand the internals of SQLite. I can imagine that the `LIMIT` clause is parsed and executed before the `SELECT` query is parsed and executed. Hence, it cannot make use of tables from outer queries. This is speculation, but it would explain what is happening.

Unfortunately, SQLite doesn't support window functions or similar functionality. So, doing what you want is rather complicated and computationally expensive. You might be better off doing this at the application layer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It does indeed make sense that it would try to build the `LIMIT` clause as a constant value. I've looked over the source code, but have not found the exact part yet. I agree that doing this in the application layer is likely the way to go. It's obvious really, which is why I did not mention it explicitly in the question. I'm going to wait a bit more to see if someone who knows this more intimately comes around. If not, this is likely the right long comment.